# Wordpress перенос на локалку. Запускается рабочая версия сайта вместо локальной

Tags: sql, wordpress, openserver

Перенёс ,рабочий сайт на локалку (Open Server). При запуске сайта с локалки запускается рабочий сайт. В SQL в файле wp_options были заменены поля "SiteUrl" и "Home" на название тестового сайта. Помогите решить проблему с переходом на рабочий сайт ) Возможно ,что то ещё не поменял

Comment: вырубить кеш если есть, проверить htaccess, проверить тему на наличие хардовых редиректов, проверить наличие плагинов для редиректов

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562